# Ansible Playbook - Synchronize module - Register variable and with_items

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to write a playbook that will rsync the folders from source to target after a database refresh. Our Peoplesoft HR application also requires a filesystem refresh along with database. I'm new to ansible and not an expert with python. I've written this but my playbook fails if any of the with_items doesn't exist. I'd like to use this playbook for all apps and the folders may differ between apps. How can I skip the folders that doesn't exist in source. I'm passing `{{ target }}` at command line.

```
---
- hosts: '<hostname>'
  remote_user: <user>

  tasks:
    - shell: ls -l /opt/custhome/prod/
      register: folders

    - name:  "Copy PROD filesystem to target"
      synchronize:
        src: "/opt/custhome/prod/{{ item }}"
        dest: "/opt/custhome/dev/"
        delete: yes
      when: "{{ folders == item }}"
      with_items:
        - 'src/cbl/'
        - 'sqr/'
        - 'bin/'
        - 'NVISION/'
```

In this case, NVISION doesn't exist in HR app but it does in FIN app. But the playbook is failing coz that folder doesn't exist in source.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [find module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/find_module.html) to find and store paths to source folders and then to iterate over results. Example playbook:

```
- hosts: '<hostname>'
  remote_user: <user>

  tasks:
    - name: find all directories
      find:
        file_type: directory
        paths: /opt/custhome/prod/
        patterns:
          - "src"
          - "sqr"
          - "bin"
      register: folders

    #debug to understand contents of {{ folders }} variable
    # - debug: msg="{{ folders }}"

    - name:  "Copy PROD filesystem to target"
      synchronize:
        src: "{{ item.path }}"
        dest: "/opt/custhome/dev/"
        delete: yes
      with_items: "{{ folders.files }}"
```

You may want to use `recurse` to descend into subdirectories and `use_regex` to use the power of python regex instead of shell globbing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Andrew. Actually I found a way but your's is much better. What I ended up doing was:
 - shell: ls -l /opt/ppscust/{{ target[:3] }}/{{ target[:3] }}prd/ | grep -e "src" -e "sqr" -e "bin" -e "NVISION" | awk '{print $9}'

      register: folders

and pass folders.stdout_lines in with_items. I'll try your way coz I like it better. Thanks!!!